# How to send cursor "home" in PHP

Tags: php, browser, cursor-position

I am using **echo** to display output to the browser window. I have a **while** loop calling a function that displays the values on a two-dimensional grid, essentially like a table. As things are, calculations are made, and the table is rendered line-by-line to the screen as those calculations are made.

However, if I update the table, showing changes caused by subsequent calculations, I have to reprint the entire table below the first. I would like to return the cursor to the top-left corner and print the update *over* the original, so that the table appears just to update itself at the time of (re-) calculation. Is this possible using PHP?

I have found various references to this general question, but none in the context of the browser. (With browsers, the term "cursor" is generally used to refer to the pointer.)

Comment: To echo the table is really fast, I suppose that the problem is to do all calculations again. You have to put the values in an database and then you need of to recalculate only the interested parameter, update the table and then echo the table with ALL parameters again

Comment: Thank you, @AntonioAbrantes. My question was more relating to the presentation. I do not want to have each update of my table reprinted down the screen in the browser, but rather have the screen "refreshed", and I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: Not sure that this can be done. PHP isn't exactly sending output to the browser window. The outputs are being gathered on server side into a file that is then served up by the web server and interpreted by the user's browser (in essence). You could give the table style of position: absolute, left: 0, width:100%, top: 0; height:100%; z-index:1; then when done and you start the next table, every thing the same but z-index: 2 (incrementing as you go along).

Comment: Thank you, @Yishmeray. Yes, I think that you have confirmed my suspicions. I have written another related question that is perhaps leading more to the crux of my problem: how do we present data in this manner? If it can be done in HTML and CSS, it can therefore be done in PHP. But I am not sure how to approach this from a structural point of view.